# R: If statement function with apply

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID  Value
1    0
2   100
3   200
4    0
```

I want to write a function that produces "Hi" if the value in the "Value" column is equal to 0, else "Bye." The result should be:

```
Answer
Hi
Bye
Bye
Hi
```

Here's the code I tried:

```
Type <- function(df){
  if(df$Value == 0)
    "Hi"
  else
    "Bye"
}

apply(X = df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = Type)
```

However, I get this error:

```
Error in Test_Customer$Pipe : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Could someone help me fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: Learn to use `ifelse`. The `if`-function is not designed to work on vectors.

Answer (score 2):

`apply()` is meant to be used with matrices, not data.frames. It actually converts your data.frame to a matrix. So when it runs, it passes in rows or columns as simple atomic vectors. It does not subset data.frames. You cannot use `$` with atomic vectors, hence your error message.

You don't need `apply()` for your example. A simple `ifelse()` would work

```
ifelse(df$Value==0, "Hi,"Bye")
```

The `ifelse()` function is vectorized to it will work on a column of data at a time. (The `if` statement is not vectorized).

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 c('Bye', 'Hi')[(df1$Value==0)+1L]
 #[1] "Hi"  "Bye" "Bye" "Hi"
```

Or use `factor`

```
factor(df1$Value!=0, labels=c('Hi', 'Bye'))
#[1] Hi  Bye Bye Hi 
#Levels: Hi Bye
```